# Помогите с ошибкой RandomForest в Python could not allocate bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение

Ребят привет, такая проблема. Загрузил свой датасет, если он маленький, то всё работает, а если загрузить 4gb или больше (основной у меня на 35gb), то вылезает вот такая ошибка:

MemoryError: could not allocate 13485735936 bytes

Что с этим делать? ОЗУ у меня 16 gb

Мой датасет (на 4gb)
0         1       2       3       4       5       6 
0   7894.0  8185.0  9493.0  8662.0  19415.0 13716.0 10658.0
1   7930.0  8219.0  9481.0  8687.0  19156.0 13726.0 10712.0
2   7898.0  8231.0  9501.0  8706.0  19210.0 13684.0 10682.0
3   7909.0  8220.0  9519.0  8733.0  19107.0 13599.0 10635.0
4   7858.0  8222.0  9500.0  8736.0  18907.0 13588.0 10693.0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
9808450 8996.0  9727.0  10756.0 11150.0 14640.0 17862.0 14758.0
9808451 8707.0  9687.0  10750.0 11160.0 14626.0 17556.0 14749.0
9808452 8797.0  9678.0  10761.0 11236.0 15000.0 17699.0 14672.0
9808453 8800.0  9721.0  10813.0 11320.0 15059.0 17735.0 14715.0
9808454 8865.0  9728.0  10637.0 11274.0 14651.0 17880.0 15305.0

 9808455 rows × 7 columns

Мой отрывок кода:

```
f #вывод датасета
X=f.iloc[:, :-1]
X=f
y=f.iloc[: , 1]
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)
clf = clf.fit(X, y)
```

Ошибка: MemoryError: could not allocate 13485735936 bytes

Comment: Что не так? у меня в коде так и написано, просто не стал писать строку с загрузкой csv файла, f выводит его на экран

Comment: Хорошо. Тогда я только само размещение сейчас выполнил по правилам сайта. Из-за размещения не по стандарту не был уверен, что это не ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо, на самом деле еще не до конца разобрался как редактировать красиво код на сайте

Comment: проще всего `~~~` на строке выше кода и `~~~` на строке ниже.